# Why my mysql query is working slow?

Tags: php, mysql, join, max

I have a query which fetch the records of 2nd highest date from db. My query working well but it take too much time in execution. How can i execute my query quickly.

Comment: a good question. Use EXPLAIN before your query to see what is wrong, or post the result

Comment: @BerndBuffen i will try it

Comment: Post the Result then i can take a look

Comment: @BerndBuffen I posted the result of my query see my update question

Comment: Sunny, @BerndBuffen is requesting the results of the `EXPLAIN` query, not the results of your actual data query. Also, it would help if you tell us what indexes are in your `og_ratings` table.

Comment: @BerndBuffen i update my question with EXPLAIN result

Comment: @OllieJones i update my question with EXPLAIN result

Comment: @Jaydee i have no any concept of INDEXES can you please help me

Comment: @OllieJones i update my question with index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to take this a bit differently than others... Am I missing something or aside from the obvious indexing optimizations which all your joins are on primary keys to the lookups -- is your criteria accurate?

Here is what I mean... Your final WHERE clause..

```
   WHERE
         r.client_id IN ( SELECT opinion_id 
                             FROM pacra_client_opinion_relations
                            WHERE client_id = 50 )
```

You are asking for a CLIENT_ID being in a select result of an OPINION_ID but only looking for opinions for client_ID = 50.  What is the context of the Opinion_id.

CLARIFICATION of Client vs Opinion from your table "pacra_client_opinion_relations"  Lets look at sample data as below

```
Opinion_ID    Client_ID   Other...
1             28          ...
2             35          ...
3             50          ...
4             2           ...
5             50          ...
6             6           ...
7             50          ...
8             4           ...
```

If your query is all OPINION_IDs for client_id = 50, you would return OPINION_ID #s 3, 5 and 7.  Since your where clause is asking for the CLIENT_ID IN the select of Opinions, you are now grabbing data for clients 3, 5 and 7 and have NOTHING to do with client #50 you originally started looking at.

Also... if you are looking only for things from "Client_ID = 50", then your prior queries trying to get the SECOND to most recent notification date, you are querying ALL Clients.  If you add a where clause for "Client_ID = 50", then you will only get those and not the 2nd to recent notification of ALL clients.

To clarify the MAX() less than the inner MAX().  Ex data from ratings you would get the following...

```
og_ratings (assuming this data is pre-sorted per client for sample purposes)
client_id  notification_date
13         Sep 5      <- You want THIS entry if it was client 13 included
13         Sep 14     <- Most recent for client 13
28         Sep 1
28         Sep 8
28         Sep 10     <- You want THIS entry if client 28 included
28         Sep 11     <- Most recent for client 28
29         Sep 4      <- You want THIS entry if client 29 included
29         Sep 11     <- Most recent for client 29
43         Sep 16     <- Most recent for client 43 and no prior, 
                         this would never show as only one entry for client
50         Sep 2
50         Sep 9
50         Sep 12     <- You want THIS entry for client 50
50         Sep 15     <- Most recent for client 50
```

Based on the sample data, you would get... Different clients could have distinctly different 2nd from latest dates

```
client_id  notification_date
13         Sep 5
28         Sep 10
29         Sep 4 
50         Sep 12
```

If all you cared about in your OUTERMOST query was client 50, and your actual data had hundreds of clients (or even thousands of clients), you are querying ALL clients.  You could limit your inner query specifically for client 50 via...

```
 og_ratings r INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
      client_id, 
      max(notification_date) notification_2nd_date
   FROM 
      og_ratings
   WHERE
      (client_id, notification_date) 
         NOT IN ( SELECT client_id, max(notification_date)
                     FROM og_ratings 
                     GROUP BY client_id )
   GROUP BY 
      client_id
   ORDER BY
      client_id DESC
```

could be adjusted to...

```
 og_ratings r INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
      client_id, 
      max(notification_date) notification_2nd_date
   FROM 
      og_ratings
   WHERE
      client_id = 50    <--- ADDED TO WHERE CLAUSE for CLIENT 50 ONLY
      AND (client_id, notification_date) 
         NOT IN ( SELECT client_id, max(notification_date)
                     FROM og_ratings 
                     WHERE client_id = 50    <--- ADDED HERE TOO FOR CLIENT 50
                     GROUP BY client_id )
   GROUP BY 
      client_id
   ORDER BY
      client_id DESC
```

and it would only return the SINGLE record for client 50 vs dates for ALL clients

```
client_id  notification_date
50         Sep 12
```

Lastly, and in many times of offering MySQL queries, I have offered using the keyword STRAIGHT_JOIN.  This basically tells MySQL to query in the order you told it to...  Sometimes when (such as your case), you have a bunch of lookup tables, it might be trying to think for you and use a lookup table first due to low record counts (or what/however) it applies the query.

SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN ... rest of query

If I am accurate on my assumptions, a more simplified query could also be done, I am just trying to explain the different pieces that I see as questionable...  Finally, as you see the sample data I have, if you could prepare sample data on this and future of what you have and what you are trying to get might help...

Comment: My `client_id` having multiple `opinion_id`. Your answer is good but it is difficult to understand for me because i am very new in coding.

Comment: @sunny, revised my answer... take a look and see if clarifications help you and my interpretation of data and what you APPEAR to be looking for.

Comment: but i want all records against client_id.As you know My client_id have multiple opinion_id. I want to fetch all record of opinion_id against client_id. For this can you help me?

Comment: Thanks for my help. I found solutions from your answer. But i made change in query to find all opinions against client id ` SELECT client_id, max(notification_date) notification_2nd_date
    FROM og_ratings
    WHERE client_id IN (SELECT `opinion_id` FROM `pacra_client_opinion_relations` WHERE `client_id` = 50 ) AND
      (client_id, notification_date) NOT IN (
        SELECT client_id, max(notification_date)
        FROM og_ratings GROUP BY client_id
          ORDER BY  client_id DESC)
    GROUP BY client_id`

Answer (score 0):

Below fields should be indexed to get performance-

```
Table : og_ratings

notification_date
pacra_action
pacra_outlook
pacra_lterm
pacra_sterm
```

You may try with individual or combined index by which you get better performance.

If you show all tables structure with index details then can help you better.

**Update for Index creation:**

```
alter table og_ratings 
add index idx_pacra_action(pacra_action), 
add index idx_pacra_outlook(pacra_outlook), 
add index idx_pacra_lterm(pacra_lterm), 
add index idx_pacra_sterm(pacra_sterm);
```

**2nd Edit due to change in query logic:**

Actually your query is logically is not correct as you are tying to pass 2 parameters in not in clause like `where (client_id, notification_date) not in (SELECT client_id, MAX(notification_date) FROM og_ratings GROUP BY client_id)`

So check below query if it provides you your desired results and should be fast-

```
SELECT r.client_id,c.id,t.id,a.id,o.id,c.name AS opinion, r.notification_date, t.title AS ttitle,a.title AS atitle,o.title AS otitle, l.title AS ltitle, s.title AS stitle, r.opinion_id, pc.id, r.pr_client_id AS pr_client, pc.address, pc.liaison_one, city.id, pc.head_office_id, city.city, pc.title AS cname 
FROM (SELECT a.client_id, a.notification_date, a.rating_type_id, a.pacra_action, a.pacra_outlook, a.pacra_lterm, a.pacra_sterm, a.opinion_id, a.pr_client_id 
FROM (SELECT t.client_id, t.notification_date, t.rating_type_id, t.pacra_action, t.pacra_outlook, t.pacra_lterm, t.pacra_sterm, pr.opinion_id, pr.client_id AS pr_client_id, 
               CASE 
                 WHEN @category != t.client_id THEN @rownum := 1 
                 ELSE @rownum := @rownum + 1 
               END AS rank,
               @category := t.client_id AS var_category
          FROM og_ratings t
          JOIN pacra_client_opinion_relations pr ON pr.opinion_id = r.client_id 
          JOIN (SELECT @rownum := NULL, @category := '') r 
          WHERE pr.client_id = 50
          ORDER BY t.client_id,t.notification_date DESC) a
      WHERE x.rank=2) r 
LEFT JOIN og_companies c ON r.client_id = c.id 
LEFT JOIN og_rating_types t ON r.rating_type_id = t.id 
LEFT JOIN og_actions a ON r.pacra_action = a.id 
LEFT JOIN og_outlooks o ON r.pacra_outlook = o.id 
LEFT JOIN og_lterms l ON r.pacra_lterm = l.id 
LEFT JOIN og_sterms s ON r.pacra_sterm = s.id 
LEFT JOIN pacra_clients pc ON pc.id = r.pr_client_id 
LEFT JOIN city ON city.id = pc.head_office_id
```

As I have not executed this query, so if you get any syntax error etc then you can create a sqlfiddle so that I can correct it.

Comment: What you mean? How i can shoe you my indexes? Can you please tell me. i am ready to show all indexes but how? i need help

Comment: @sunny https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-index.html Your life will be a lot easier by using search engines :)

Comment: @Jonast92 i use this link and i post index of my table in my question

Comment: @Jonast92 Now i just want to know How i can use index in my query

Comment: @sunny you don't need to change query. You can use fields that are indexed in query

Comment: @sunny: create index as per my sql updated in my post and check your query performance. If you show your tables structure (data type etc) and other tables index also then we can check other performance issues also.

Comment: @ZafarMalik I alter my table now what i can do next?

Comment: There is no any performance in query. I still execute in too much time

Answer (score 0):

Add index to your reference fields I mean columns which in `ON` part like `r.client_id, c.id`

```
  LEFT JOIN og_companies c ON r.client_id = c.id
  LEFT JOIN og_rating_types t ON r.rating_type_id = t.id
  LEFT JOIN og_actions a ON r.pacra_action = a.id
  LEFT JOIN og_outlooks o ON r.pacra_outlook = o.id
  LEFT JOIN og_lterms l ON r.pacra_lterm = l.id
  LEFT JOIN og_sterms s ON r.pacra_sterm = s.id
  LEFT JOIN pacra_client_opinion_relations pr ON pr.opinion_id = c.id
  LEFT JOIN pacra_clients pc ON pc.id = pr.client_id
  LEFT JOIN city ON city.id = pc.head_office_id
```

so how can you add an index on mysql?

SQL>> `ALTER TABLE your_table_name ADD INDEX (your_column_name);`

ALSO for better performance your join columns should have the same structure. For example if your column_1 is int(11) unsigned other side should be same.

> - Make certain you have indexes on all columns that are part of table    joins
> - Make certain you have indexes on any column used in a filter
> - Explicitly define primary keys Explicitly define foreign key    relationships
> - For large data sets, use table partitioning Define columns as NOT NULL where possible

http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/database-query-performance